# Ayuda con collapse nav bootstrap y js

Tags: javascript

Tengo un navbar que tiene un elemento de llámanos que abre un popup que muestra los numero telefónicos pero cuando le doy click a ese apartado el menú navbar no se cierra y se queda abajo el popup y no se muestran los números como hacer que se cierre el navbar al darle click en llamanos(en modo responsive) espero me ayuden[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Empresa
            Servicios
            Contacto
            Llámanos

1234567890

+123456789098

1234560987

Comment: Francisco, bienvenido a SOes. La verdad encuentro muy dificil de entender tu pregunta, aun con tu imagen. Por favor lee el articulo: [ask]. Despues porfavor incluye el codigo que estas usando para esta parte de tu web siguiendo los lineamientos establecidos en el articulo: [mcve].

Comment: gracias por el comentario, ya lo leí y tomaré en cuenta para la siguiente ves, a lo que iba es que quiero que el popup que al presionar llamanos en el navbar, este se suba (el navbar), pero que esto solo lo haga en modo responsive te muestro el link  http://201.160.106.178/desarrollo/proyectos/femtesa/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con `jQuery` puedes hacer algo como:

```
$("#llamanos").click(function(){
    $("#navbar).slideUp()
})
```

Este código lo que haría es que al darle clic al botón en mención tu navbar se cerrará de manera animada en un efecto de desplazamiento hacia arriba.

Otra solución que podrías hacer es simplemente a los estilos css del popup agregar un z-index para colocarlo por encima de todos los demás elementos

```
#popup{
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Espero que te sirva. Saludos.

Comment: me sirvio, solo cambie la clase a la cual se dirige, muchas gracias!